# Do I have to pay this cancellation fee?

Tags: legal, europe, regulations, cancellations, iceland

I reserved a motorhome in Iceland.  On the invoice the cancellation policy was listed.  I didn't pay the invoice and then cancelled the reservation 2 months prior to the starting date. I cancelled because i found out that it's not safe (due to weather) driving a motorhome in Iceland in November .All the campsites are closed and the laws changed recently that you now cannot park wherever you like.  Their website did not display this information and they've sent me an invoice for 75% of the total which is 1246 euros or $1400!

I thought the cancellation policy was not effective until I actually paid the first invoice. I think it's a crime that they want that much money even I cancelled two months ahead of time.

I want to find out if I am legally responsible to pay it out? What are my options here?

Comment: I can't speak definitively for Iceland's laws, but typically contracts become enforceable once you agree to them, not just when you pay up. Chances are you'll need to consult a lawyer.

Comment: Likely when you booked, the form included a little agree to the terms clause. The date you agreed sets everything in motion, not the date you pay.

Comment: You say that the cancellation policy was listed on the *invoice*? An invoice is generated only after making a contract, and the cancellation policy should have been part of the contract (usually part of th eterms and ocnditions) already ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be migrated to Law.SE.

Comment: I'm voting to leave open as we have entertained [similar questions](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/72621/32134) before, and cancellation of reservations is an essential part of travel.

Comment: Read the terms on the rental site to determine your obligations.  Then see @GeorgeY's post for options.

Comment: *On the invoice the cancellation policy was listed* **How about quoting that here** so that we know what you're talking about?

Answer (score 23):

From the way you described it, it looks like you agreed to a contract with specific terms, which include cancellation penalty. Unless the contract stated the penalty would only apply once you made your first payment, then you owe the cancellation fees, and thus **yes, you are responsible to pay it**. Paying them would of course be your first option.

Your second option is **to negotiate**. If the reason for your cancellation is the recent change in law (which happened AFTER you signed the contract), you may have some recourse. In this case you should reach out to them, and explain the situation. You would still likely have to pay some cancellation fee, but this way you can have it reduced.

And of course your third option is **not to pay**. If you did not give them the credit card, and they do not have physical presence in your country, their chance to collect it are rather low. This however does not invalidate the debt - for example, one possibility is that they can sue you in Iceland in your absence (if in your contract you agreed to Icelandic jurisdiction), and get the default judgment. This may be enforceable in your country, and would certainly apply if you ever visit Iceland again. Thus attempting to resolve it peacefully with both parties satisfied may be a better strategy in the long run.

This depends on the assumption that the contract you've agreed to contain the cancellation provision, requiring you to pay 75% of the total amount in case of cancellation. If it contain nothing, and the company just made up a number, the situation of course is different.

Comment: are you seriously _**recommending an illegal activity**_ because 'OP might get away with it'? There are countries where _this alone_ is already punishable by law. I would expect that SE does not support such recommendations, but it seems people love it.

Comment: @Aganju Where do you see a recommendation? I don't see one.

Comment: the word is not used, but he list "_your third option is not to pay._" Illegal options are not options.

Comment: @Aganju of course not paying is an option. Whether it is a sensible one depends. Frankly if I was in the OP's position (and somewhat surprising that they haven't secured this amount up front as a deposit) I'd be minded to investigate it.

Comment: @Aganju You must be using a rather weird dictionary, because by most definitions it certainly is an option. Possibly not a very good one and morally dubious, but depending on the circumstances a possibility.

Comment: Ok, maybe I'm having a bad day and are too overeager. I stand corrected.

Comment: @Aganju What is illegal? There is **no** concept of legal/illegal without reference to a country laws or international laws. AFAIK not paying in this case may be illegal *in Iceland*, but not in an unrelated state. Whether it is *moral* or *immoral* is an other matter.

Comment: If the cancellation policy is only noted on the invoice, how could it be part of the contract?

Comment: @Aganju: contract disputes, when one side does not act according to contract, have nothing to do with "illegal activity". They are covered by civil law, and are resolved in civil courts. This happens on daily basis. If you know countries where not performing according to contract by itself is considered "illegal activity", please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Contracts are binding.

You accepted a contract, and no matter how outrageous the conditions are, you are bound by it. You cannot apply the american 'feel' that the law protects you from 'surprising' fine print; other countries have other laws, and especially this protection is mostly non-existent in Other parts of the world. *You are expected to read what you sign before you sign.*

In addition, consider their position - this is just an example, of course - imagine they had no motorhome available for your booking period, and now *shipped* one to iceland just to rent it to you. Now you don't want it, and they sit on the cost.

Comment: Iceland is EU, hence surprising T&C are invalid. Crf. http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/consumers/unfair-treatment/unfair-contract-terms/index_en.htm On the one hand, cancellation fees by themselves can hardly be called surprising. Then again, 75% of the full rate when cancelling 2 months in advance seems unreasonably high to me (cf. item 5 of the above link)

Comment: `the american 'feel' that the law protects you from 'surprising' fine print`  The what, now? Dunno where you got that impression, but American law most certainly does not protect you form surprising fine print.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Iceland is _not_ in the EU.

Comment: "no matter how outrageous the conditions are, you are bound by it" That's not true. A contract can never bind you to do something illegal, for example.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Iceland may not be part of the EU, but as an EEA member it's bound by EU Regulations. In particular, Consumer Protection is part of the first pillar of the EU which regulates trade, and it is fully in force in Iceland.

Answer (score -2):

Many of the other answers and comments are operating under the assumption that a binding contract has been made; it is not at all clear to me that this is correct. Some of the moralizing seems particularly uncalled for.

Typically (western common-law based) courts require some sort of reasonably tangible consideration to change hands on both sides in order for a contract to exist at all; clarifying this point is the reason why things are often sold for a dollar (or other token sum) rather than simply being given away.

In this case, I can't see where either party has received anything of value; the rental agent has received nothing from you (you did not pay the invoice), and it seems unlikely that a judge would consider that reserving an RV for you two months from now is of any value. (Given that this is an easily reversible decision)

Of course it is possible that Iceland has some sort of unique Viking vacation rental laws that you could run afoul of, but barring this I would strongly suspect that the rental agent is fishing for a sucker, and you should not pay.

Comment: Please explain what consideration the rental agent has received?

Comment: @jkf Consideration needs to be *specified* for the contract to be formed, but generally you don't have to exchange anything *immediately* just to form a contract - mutual promises to exchange in the future are enough. If you had to actually exchange goods on *formation* of the contract, that would make contracting for things in the future very difficult. (IANAL)

Comment: "Western common law" - that would be British common law. Most of Europe including Iceland does _not_ use British common law.

Comment: Wow, I am going down in flames here. My **point** is that nobody has taken the trouble to look into what the law might actually say about this in Iceland, and are leaving crazy answers and comments based on some weird moral code which would not fly in the courts of any country with which I am familiar. IANALE but part of the point in contractors taking deposits is getting some provable consideration out there on the part of the contractee, so they don't have to dance around the issue in case of a dispute. I personally would lose no sleep over telling this vendor to KMA, morally or legally.

Comment: @MSalters "British common law" would be "English common law". Scotland has its own legal system (which, coincidentally, does not include the concept of "consideration").

Comment: @jkf The consideration the company has received is the promise that a vehicle will be rented at a particular price on a particular day; the consideration that the customer has received is the promise that a vehicle will be available to rent on those terms. And that's assuming that the concept of "consideration" even exists in Icelandic law, which is my no means a given. Consideration seems to have been an invention of the English courts and most European legal systems are not based on English law.

Comment: @jkf: what you essentially said that all plane ticket purchase contracts aren't contracts until you actually walked into a plane. Right?

Comment: @DavidRicherby I would suggest that in this case the invoice itself represents the contract, and the fact that the OP did not pay suggests that the contract was not agreed to. Both points of view are defensible, which is why I don't see any reason that the OP should pay this fee -- to quote Apple Computer, "Sosumi"!

Comment: @GeorgeY. Actually this is kind of true -- if something goes wrong with a flight you will find that the airline is under no obligation to take you anywhere. This is more due to the specific terms of their sales contract though.

Comment: Note that airlines do not attempt to enforce any kind of cancellation fee **until after you have paid for the ticket**.

Comment: @jkf: but something has to change hands on both sides (according to you), so simply paying the airline is not enough as I've got nothing back except the reservation.

Comment: They give you a ticket saying you can get on their plane -- that is "something" even if it is in electronic form. This is not according to me, this is pretty well established law and accounts for some of the weird quirks of North American/Commonwealth business. Note that assuming Iceland is governed somewhat by EU consumer law (as someone asserts above), the OP may have the right to sue *in his/her own jurisdiction* so these concepts may in fact apply in the case that the vendor has charged the deposit to the OP's credit card or something.

Comment: Then when they made a reservation for OP, they promised that a vehicle would be available to OP (and not to someone else) on those dates - this is as much "something" as the plane ticket reservation.

Comment: That is arguable, as unlike an airline which has scheduled flights there is no real indication that an RV was actually set aside or even secured. However, going back to my actual answer, the main problem is that the agent received absolutely nothing from the OP. Since the fee was only listed **on the invoice**, this was the OP's first chance to reject that part of the contract, which he did, by not paying the invoice. The rental agent could argue otherwise if he chose to try to sue the OP, but this seems unlikely to happen IRL. Repeating myself again, the agent is fishing for easy money.

Comment: @jkf "I would suggest that in this case the invoice itself represents the contract" No, because an invoice is not sent until payment is due. "Both points of view are defensible, which is why I don't see any reason that the OP should pay this fee" That's not how the law works. One of the views is correct, under Icelandic law. That is what determines whether he has to pay.

Comment: @DavidRicherby "Their website did not display this information" ... "On the invoice the cancellation policy was listed."  How can the OP have agreed to this policy prior to receiving the invoice? And how else to reject it than not paying the invoice?